# Is there a way to stop/disable a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have running multiple Google Cloud functions. One is not operating well, so I want to stop them until I've fixed the situation.

I have seen that I can remove the function, but is there a way to disable and later; enable the function?

Comment: In my case, I would need to add "without redeploying" to your question. I just want to pause one of the firestore triggers while I make some changes to the database, then I'd enable again

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot disable a function. Just comment the function body. It would be a good practice to log the call in the console and then return null so you can keep track whenever the function is invoked.

Answer (score 11):

Follow up for anyone else looking for this, I created an ENV variable and added an if check before my function executes. Ex:

```
if os.environ['functionOn'] == 'true':
    # insert previous function code here
```

Can change function on/off with ENV variable change from console + redeploy.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is late but what I did is that I deleted/commented the function I don't need and deployed again using firebase deploy --only functions . Once run, it shows that the function is being deleted. Hope this helps[GCF Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/246Vu.png)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I found that too. Is there a way to deploy only one function? As my development grow the longer it takes to deploy :(

Comment: Sure firebase  deploy --only functions:myFunc

Where myFunc is th3 name of the function to deploy

Comment: Thanks. I also found an option to delete the function from the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Do not export the function. That way you can still keep it unmodified and yet be able to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Many of my cloud functions trigger on pub/sub topics.  I just created a topic called Disabled.  And updated the trigger of each topic triggered CF to that Disabled topic, and redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

There's no button or switch you can turn to "switch it off". And I prefer to maintan a "single source of truth" when developing, so I removed them. If you have a CI integrated in your git (like gitlab CI) it should be just one click to re-deploy

Answer (score -5):

Came across this via google and it seems you can pause your functions from running within https://console.cloud.google.com/

Comment: So how do you do that? This is a non-answer