# Google Cloud Functions REST API, functions.patch Error: There must be exactly one trigger specified for a function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

When I excute the code below I get the message "There must be exactly one trigger specified for a function". When I specify the trigger I get "Internal error encountered." with every combination I try.

I try to achieve to disable a cloud function and since there is no official way, I figured I patch the function to something like timeout 0s or set entryPoint to something that doesn't exist, but nothing works.

```
def patch_gcf_trigger(token_gcf_api):

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token_gcf_api,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    url = 'https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXXXX/locations/us-central1/functions'
    r_dataj = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text
    r_data = json.loads(r_dataj)

    functions = r_data['functions']

    for func in functions:

        func_name = func['name']

        if 'cost_capper' in func_name:

            url = 'https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/%s' % func_name
            payload = {}
            # payload['eventTrigger'] = {}
            # payload['eventTrigger']['eventType'] = 'google.pubsub.topic.publish'
            # payload['eventTrigger']['resource'] = 'projects/XXXXX/topics/testt'
            # payload['eventTrigger']['service'] = 'pubsub.googleapis.com'
            payload['entryPoint'] = 'testt'
            # payload['timeout'] = '120s'
            payloadj = json.dumps(payload)
            r_dataj = requests.patch(url, payloadj, headers = headers).text
            r_data = json.loads(r_dataj)
            print(r_data)
```

The function look like this:

```
{
    "name": "projects/XXXXX/locations/us-central1/functions/cost_capper",
    "eventTrigger": {
        "eventType": "google.pubsub.topic.publish",
        "resource": "projects/XXXXX/topics/test_billing",
        "service": "pubsub.googleapis.com",
        "failurePolicy": {}
    },
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "entryPoint": "main_start",
    "timeout": "60s",
    "availableMemoryMb": 256,
    "serviceAccountEmail": "XXXXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    "updateTime": "2020-03-11T15:03:15.217Z",
    "versionId": "5",
    "labels": {
        "deployment-tool": "console-cloud"
    },
    "sourceUploadUrl": "XXXXXXX",
    "runtime": "python37",
    "ingressSettings": "ALLOW_ALL"
}
```

Comment: There are some strategies to disable Cloud Functions described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681644/is-there-a-way-to-stop-disable-a-google-cloud-function). Maybe one of them will suffice for you.

Comment: thansk I saw this thread. My goal is to disable execution/the trigger. But you have options for that. I now called the gcloud functiond delete and deploy commands to delete and then deploy the function again. I manager however to path app engine successfully and I think I also can do it for cloud functions now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to try the REST queries in detail in the "Try it out" sidebar in the documentation, the error messages are more detailed there. And have a look in your browser's tools to see the actual sent url.

Here is what I missed:

You have to provide the parameter updateMask in addition and state there which field you want to update, in my case field eventTrigger.
Also you have to send that as a url parameter while the json bit goes in the request body.

Its done like this with the Python requests library:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token_gae_api,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

url = 'https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/%s' % func_name

params = {}
params['updateMask'] ='eventTrigger'

payload = {}
payload['eventTrigger'] = {}
payload['eventTrigger']['eventType'] = 'google.pubsub.topic.publish'
payload['eventTrigger']['resource'] = 'projects/XXXXX/topics/cwm_trigger_topic'
payload['eventTrigger']['service'] = 'pubsub.googleapis.com'

r_dataj = requests.patch(url, json=payload, params=params, headers=headers).text
r_data = json.loads(r_dataj)

print(r_data)
```

Comment: is someone wonders how I disable the trigger of the function. I oatch the function to event trigger when on a bucket gets something deleted. I dont use bucket of course. To activate teh trigger again I patch to the original tigger, a pubsub topic.